# Zooming in image using scrollview Xcode

Tags: xcode4.3

I am trying an iPad application using Xcode. I am just a beginner so there are things I don't know how to do. In my app, I have some images showing one by one by scrollview. Now, I want them to zoom in when double tap and zoom out when double tap again. Can anyone tell me how to zoom in and out using the same scrollview which is used to display all the images?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer the Apple Documents... [Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html)